# MySQL Database replication on Amazon EC2 error 2013

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, database-replication

I am currently facing an issue with trying to create a mysql master/slave server on amazon EC2 using redhat os. For the most part I have followed this tutorial (http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-set-up-mysql-database-replication-on-fedora-10).

When calling SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G; I get:

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
          Slave_IO_State: Connecting to master
              Master_Host: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
              Master_User: slave_user
              Master_Port: 3306
            Connect_Retry: 60
          Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000001
      Read_Master_Log_Pos: 337
           Relay_Log_File: mysqld-relay-bin.000001
            Relay_Log_Pos: 4
    Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000001
         Slave_IO_Running: No
        Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
          Replicate_Do_DB: testdb
      Replicate_Ignore_DB: 
       Replicate_Do_Table: 
   Replicate_Ignore_Table: 
  Replicate_Wild_Do_Table: 
Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table:
                Last_Errno: 0
               Last_Error: 
             Skip_Counter: 1
      Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 337
          Relay_Log_Space: 106
          Until_Condition: None
           Until_Log_File: 
            Until_Log_Pos: 0
       Master_SSL_Allowed: No
       Master_SSL_CA_File: 
       Master_SSL_CA_Path: 
          Master_SSL_Cert: 
        Master_SSL_Cipher: 
           Master_SSL_Key: 
    Seconds_Behind_Master: NULL
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
            Last_IO_Errno: 2013
            Last_IO_Error: error connecting to master 'slave_user@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:3306' - retry-time: 60  retries: 86400
           Last_SQL_Errno: 0
           Last_SQL_Error:
```

my Slave my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
server-id=2
master-host=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
master-user=slave_user
master-password=slave_password
master-connect-retry=60
replicate-do-db=mosaicschroma
skip-name-resolve

datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

and my master my.cnf

```
[mysqld]

log-bin = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
binlog-do-db=mosaicschroma
server-id=1

datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

when using nmap to check if I can ping the other server and port 3306 I receive a report of filtered which I assume is correct.

Any help is greatly appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: Maybe double-check privileges on the master server: `show grants for 'slave_user'@'%'`

Comment: Thanks for the response. After checking, slave_user already has grant replication slave

Comment: The other thing that comes to mind is the security group / firewall rules. The 'filtered' response from nmap isn't convincing. Can you use the cli mysql client to connect from the slave to the master? Are these VPC or classic EC2 instances?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try first from the slave machine:

```
telnet master-machine 3306
```

If you get a garbled mysql message like this then you have no firewall connection issues:

```
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
N
5.5.34-log>W~4%]$�>eb;>gi\rGK#mysql_native_password
```

Also like `grossvogel` said, check the grants for the slave user that you are trying to use to connect to the master.

Comment: Thanks, it turns out there was an issue with my EC2 security groups, after fixing the open ports I was able to connect to the master.